# Check if atleast one of the objects string length is greater than zero in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7

I have an array with dictionaries

```
{
        Name = "Joe";
        PhoneNo = "";
},
{
        Name = "Jack ";
        PhoneNo = 3219486159;
},
{
        Name = "Jill";
        PhoneNo = "";
}
```

How do I check if atleast one of the object in NSMutableArray contains PhoneNo with length>0

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, step by step. First, you want a BOOL variable to record whether you found a phone number with length > 0. It's NO before you start searching.

```
BOOL foundNumber = NO;
```

Next, you have an array of dictionaries. How do you examine all dictionaries in that array?

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
}
```

How do you extract the "PhoneNo" value?

```
NSString* number = dict [@"PhoneNo"];
```

How do you check that the length is greater than zero?

```
if (number.length > 0)
    foundNumber = YES;
```

Now you put it all together.